# how to define what characters are considered to be part of a tagname in vim?

Tags: vim, ruby

when I'm using Ctrl-] to jump to a tagname in vim it ignores ! and ? characters which can be used in ruby as parts of identifiers. i.e. when trying to jump to 'empty?' tag it complains about missing tag 'empty'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the desired characters to the iskeyword option.  Try:

```
:set iskeyword+=!,?
```